# Excel function to get chars between hyphens

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string like:
`AB-CD-EF-GH-IK`

I wanna get `EF` between second and third hyphen.

Please help me to figure it out, Thanks

Comment: Is the string always the same length and pattern? Then use Mid()

Comment: characters are dynamic, but hyphens is static

Comment: yes. exactly. AB can be ABC

Comment: yes. all symbols between all hyphens can be 2 digits or 3, 4 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even shorter is:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),2*LEN(A1),LEN(A1)))`

Regards

Comment: Very nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not because this is the right approach, but because shorter than (what was at the time!) the accepted Answer:

```
=MID(A6,FIND("-",A6,FIND("-",A6)+1)+1,FIND("-",A6,FIND("-",A6,FIND("-",A6)+1)+1)-FIND("-",A6,FIND("-",A6)+1)-1)
```

A small point in its favour may be that it uses only two common-or-garden functions:

[MID](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mid-function) to extract the string
[FIND](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-find-function) to find the index numbers of the relevant characters.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with varying lengths of strings between the dashes. Doesn't look pretty but works.

```
=LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("-",A1),""),1,FIND("-",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("-",A1),"")),""),FIND("-",REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("-",A1),""),1,FIND("-",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("-",A1),"")),""))-1)
```

[image]